# Warning: Formik called `handleBlur`, but you forgot to pass an `id` or `name` attribute to your input

Tags: reactjs, formik

I would like to create Form using Formik. After submitting, I got following error:

```
Warning: Formik called `handleBlur`, but you forgot to pass an `id` or `name` attribute to your input
```

Here's is my code:

```js
import { useField } from 'formik';
import * as Styled from './SearchInput.styles';

const SearchInput = ({name, ...props }) => {
  const [field] = useField(name);

  return (
    <Styled.Wrapper>
      <Styled.Input {...field} {...props} placeholder="Placeholder"  />
    </Styled.Wrapper>
  );
};

export default SearchInput;
```

```js
interface Values {
    test: string;
}

const Form = () => {
    return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        test: ''
      }}
      onSubmit={(values: Values) => {
        console.log(values)
      }}
    >
    {(props: FormikProps<Values>) => (
      <FormikForm>
          <SearchInput name="test" type="text" onChange={props.handleChange} />
          <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </FormikForm>
      )}
    </Formik>
    )
  };

export default Form;
```

I know the problem is with the input component that doesn't have the built in
name property. Component is called 'Search', but if I use component called 'Input' which has name property, everything works fine.

What should I do? I am using Typescript. Extend interface will work, or what? I'm in dead end

Comment: I don't know what the `field` object contains but if it doesn't contain `name` you need put the name from the props to the input:
<Styled.Input {...field} {...props} name={name} placeholder="Placeholder"  />
Or remove props destructuring:
const [field] = useField(props.name);